# $f$ diffeomorphism $\Leftrightarrow f'(x)\cdot f'(y)>0$

Tags: real-analysis, inverse-function-theorem

Let $I\subset \mathbb R$ be an open interval and $f:I\to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function. I would like to prove the following equivalence:

> $$f:I\to\mathbb R\ \text{a diffeomorphism over $f(I)$}\Leftrightarrow
>  f'(x)\cdot f'(y)>0\ \text{for every $x,y\in I$}$$

I'm trying to prove it using the inverse function theorem.

**$\Leftarrow$**

Since $f'(x)\neq 0$, take an arbitrary $x_0\in I$, there is an open subset $U\in I$ with $x_0\in U$ such that $f_{\restriction U}:U\to f(U)$ is a diffeomorphism. I don't know how to prove the function $f$ is a diffeomorphism on the entire $I$.

$\Rightarrow$

I have no idea, I need some hints.

Comment: "$f'(x)f'(y)>0$ for every $x, y \in I$" is a fancy way of saying that $f'$ never changes sign; it is either always positive or always negative.

Comment: @Arthur What can I do with this information? thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

$\Leftarrow$: As commented by Arthur, $f'$ never changes sign on $I$. That is, there does not exist $x,y \in I$ with $f'(x)f'(y) < 0$. Moreover, this condition implies $f'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in I$, so $\mathrm Df$ is invertible on $I$. If you can also show that $f'$ is continuous, you can invoke the Inverse Function Theorem which asserts $f^{-1}:f[I] \to I$ is continuously differentiable, and hence $f$ is a $\mathrm C^1$-diffeomorphism.

$\Rightarrow:$ $f$ is a diffeomorphism implies $f' \neq 0$. Moreover, $f'$ is continuous (since $f$ is continuously differentiable), so $f'$ may never cross $0$. Hence $f'(x)f'(y) > 0$.

Comment: can we have $f'(x)<0$ for every $x\in I$? in this case we would have $f'(x)\cdot f'(y)>0$ too.

Comment: @user42912 You can.

Comment: So in the last line of your answer we could have $f'(x)\cdot f'(y)<0$  and it's not what we want. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @user42912 That would be invalid, since $f'(x) \cdot f'(y) < 0$ iff $f'(x)$ and $f'(y)$ has different signs, which by continuous differentiability and Intermediate Value Theorem implies $f'(x) = 0$ somewhere.

Comment: You're right I'm sorry.

Comment: I'm using this version of inverse function theorem: http://www.math.tamu.edu/~tvogel/410/sect116.pdf. Thus I can use it without proving $f'$ is continuous, right?

Comment: @user42912 If the theorem allows you to do it then you can do it.

Comment: My only problem to use it is it asserts there is an open subset $U\in I$ such that $f:U\to f(U)$ is a diffeomorphism. We don't necessarily have $U=I$.

Comment: @user42912 The theorem you showed is only needed for the $\Leftarrow$ direction which you are proving diffeomorphism.

Comment: Yes I know. The only thing it misses to me to understand your answer is why you can take the open set to be the whole $I$. Thank you again

Comment: @user42912 The theorem says "Then there is some open set...". The existence of the open set is what the theorem asserts, not what you need to prove from other results.

Comment: Yes I know, the problem is in your answer you said $f^{-1}:f(I)\to I$ is continuously differentiable, but I think you can't say that, the only thing you can say is there is some open set $U\in I$ such that $f_{\restriction f(U)}^{-1}:f(U)\to U$ is continuously differentiable. Did you understand my point?